# How to select rows from a data frame in which values in a given columns are not None?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to do the following:

```
df[df['colname'] != None]
```

and as a result I get:

```
KeyError: 'no item named True'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [dropna()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df.dropna(subset=['colname'])
```

or alternatively [Series.notnull](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
df[df['colname'].notnull()]
```